# When using database-migrations, how is the author name generated

Tags: grails, database-migration

When I use dbm-gorm-diff to generate changelog files, it sets the author to "username (generated)". Is there some kind to have my full name and email-address inserted instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows 7 system, it picks up the environment variable USERNAME (and probably similarly on other OSes). So you could modify this value by, for ex.,

```
set USERNAME = c089
```

and then execute dbm-gorm-diff.

or you could pass a property value from the command line as in,

> grails dbm-gorm-diff -Duser.name=c089

Though I can't seem to get rid of the "(generated)" text :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want exactly the line of code :

```
String user = (System.getProperty('user.name') ?: '').trim()
String author = user ? "$user (generated)" : 'diff-generated';
```

So áldrin is right, you can't get rid of the `generated`

That's in [this file](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/scripts/DbmCreateChangelog.groovy)